# jQuery show() has interesting and unexpected "animation" effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't mind this effect or fluke happening per say, however if it is to happen I'd like to it to not go to far off the page before it bounces back in a manor of speaking. Go to http://originalglbtexpo.com/asites/cholerose/ to see what I mean. Hit any link, watch the first thing fade away then the block that replaces it after starts off on the left and goes to far right then snaps back to its spot.

Dunno exactly how to fix this per say so I'm looking for idea's

Comment: Looks like an issue with CSS and the divs being floated. Also, it's spelled 'equipment'

Comment: Please fix the misspelling `Equiptment`.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: The snap is caused by how jQuery handles the hidden element.  I've found that if I use the `float` property on all of my `show/hide` elements, there is no snapping effect whatsoever.  If I had a better explanation, I'd post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show()` animates width and height from zero to their natural values, which may be messing with your margins. You can avoid this 'snapping' behavior by locking the width of the element in place with an `!important` declaration behind your `width: 730px` rule for `#content_wrap`.

Comment: note that if you want to cancel out ANY vertical or horizontal shifting of the element on `show()`, simply apply `!important` declarations to `height`, `margin`, `padding`, and `border-width` (i.e: any CSS property that affects the element's dimensions, in which case, you might consider using `fadeIn()` instead of `show()`).

Answer (score 0):

`$().show` eases in exactly this manner. See [the demo on the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/show/).